# Environment variable not getting set in Mac osx

Tags: macos, terminal, environment-variables, anaconda

I usually set environment variables in ~/.bash_profile in my Mac. something like:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME

export M2_HOME=/opt/mvn3.3.3
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

**This works fine for me.**

I have recently installed Anaconda from continuum. I happened to have installed it only for my own account. Thus, the environment variable which I am trying to set is like:

```
export PATH="/Users/<username>/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

**but this is not working.**

If I export the same variable for terminal session then I can access the commands for that session in terminal. I think the problem is that Anaconda is being installed only for specific user. Please help.

- Do I need to re-install it for all the users?
- Can not we set an environment variable pointing to a particular user's path?
- The bash_profile is for the same user, then why it is not working?